# Time difference between two date fields

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I have a date field names "dts" in string format. I want to find out all the records based on their time differences (in hours). The run event time should be greater than or equal to eat event.

[image]

The output should be:

[image]

Comment: Please provide desired output

Comment: @leftjoin - updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert timestamps to seconds, then subtract, divide result by 3600 to get hours, use case+count to count by ranges, something like this:

```
select count(case when diff_hrs >24 then 1 end) as more_24,
       count(case when diff_hrs <=24 then 1 end) as less_than_24,
       ...
       count(case when diff_hrs >=2 and diff_hrs <=3 then 1 end) as hrs_2_to_3,
       ...
from
(
select
abs(unix_timestamp(dts) - unix_timestamp(dts-eat)))/60/60 as diff_hrs
from table
)s;
```

Comment: what if one of the date field is with T and Z ( 2016-05-05T13:37:30Z) and the other is without (2016-05-06 13:37:30.0). Would unix_timestamp still work?

Comment: Convert dates like this: `from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2017-01-01T05:01:10Z", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' "),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

returns `2017-01-01 05:01:10`

Comment: from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(columnname, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' "),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") - would this return everything in a column in the same format?

Comment: from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dts-eat, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' "),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") - this is returning NULL

Comment: from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2017-01-01T05:01:10Z", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' "),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") - this is also returning NULL

Comment: Tested:  `select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2017-01-01T05:01:10Z", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`
OK
`2017-01-01 05:01:10`
Time taken: 0.062 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

Comment: the last one worked..i think your first answer had an extra space after 'Z'. thanks :)

Comment: if the timestamp is in PST can i use the following to convert it to UTC: to_utc_timestamp(tablename.fieldname, 'PST')

Comment: Sure you can. I have checked, it works good in Hive 1.2.1.  `select current_timestamp, to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp, 'PST');`
OK
`2017-05-29 23:51:25.719 2017-05-30 06:51:25.719`